# Search Server Express Topology Problem

Tags: sharepoint-2010, search-server-2010

Lately I've installed Search Server Express 2010. After configuring it, I tried to test search functionality - content was crawled, and found by the search mechanism, so it was OK. Problem occured when I went entered Topology for Search Service Application: Search Service Application(Central Administration -> Manage services on server -> SharePoint Server Search -> Modify Topology). I can do everything there, but when I click Cancel or Apply Topology Changes it throws me an error:

> An unhandled exception occurred in the
>   user interface.Exception Information:
>   An update conflict has occurred, and
>   you must re-try this action. The
>   object SearchConfigWizardContext
>   Name=8644038a-200f-4fd7-9842-57fc35aee1ca
>   was updated by 'my_user_name', in the w3wp (1488)
>   process, on machine 'server_name'. View the tracing
>   log for more information about the
>   conflict.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID:
>   3d4b97c0-3309-4e6e-aa55-c82d8bc57cdd

Does anybody had similar problem and knows what can be wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by reinstalling the Search Server Express.